# JasperReports v5.6.0 crashing Tomcat

Tags: java, jasper-reports, tomcat7

We are creating PDFs using *JasperReports v5.6.0*. It works fine but for the same PDF request JASPER is taking down the whole *Tomcat* server (production) every second day.

Once Tomcat server is restarted then the same PDF starts working fine until next day and then there will be another server crash due to native code i.e.; JASPER

We have narrowed it down and found out that JasperFillManager fill (...) method is responsible for the crash.

```
        LocalJasperReportsContext ctx = iniJasperReportsContext(request);  
        JasperFillManager fillmgr = JasperFillManager.getInstance(ctx);
        logger.debug(classAndMethodName + " Before Fill the report with data from dataSource");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = fillmgr.fill(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);   // Fill the report with data from dataSource. This is the method which is responsible for the Crash.
```

Since above crashed the server so Catch and the Finally blocks didn't execute as well and we don't have the exact stacktrace of the issue. Previously we were facing the same crashing issue with JASPER v5.2.0 so we migrated to JASPER v5.6.0 but unfortunately it didn't help.

Can you please advise what could be the reason and the possible solution for this severe crashing issue?

Our Environment details are as below;

java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

apache-tomcat-7.0.26

*JasperReports v5.6.0*

Comment: java version "1.7.0_09" is pretty old, and many bugs have meanwhile been fixed. Consider updating to a current 1.7.

Comment: Looks like a memory leak. check JVM logs for out of memory exception. Are you using a virtualizer?

Comment: Hi we have already checked into this and there is no Memory Leak.
Also the below line which is causing Tomcat to crash is purely a native JASPER code.

JasperPrint jasperPrint = fillmgr.fill(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);

Comment: Has a "hs_err_pid" file been created in the course of the crash? If yes, what does it say?

Comment: What do you mean by "native jasper code"?  Isn't jasper-reports implemented in Java?